# Will the set of discontinuities be Borel-measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume you have a Riemann-Integrable function $f$ on $[a,b]$. Then we know that it is Lebesgue-measurable, and it is continuous Lebesgue almost everywhere.

**Question 1:** Will the set of discontinuities be Borel-measurable?

**Question 2:** If we in addition assume that $f$ is Borel-measurable, will then the set of discontinuities be Borel-measurable?

Comment: The set of discontinuities will be $F_{\sigma}$, hence Borel-measurable. This holds for any function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and has nothing to do with Riemann-integrability.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544162/discontinuity-set-of-function-closed-and-f-sigma

Comment: @Thorgott You should add that as an answer.