# What is wrong with my solution? Proving set of all points of continuity of $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

So originally I was asked to prove that the set of all points of continuity for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable (all of my analysis so far is in $\mathbb{R}^d$). I came up this solution:

For $f$ above, let $C=\{\,\, x \in \mathbb{R}\,\, |\,\, f \,\,\text{is continuous at} \,\,x \,\,\}$. For all $a\in C$, let $B_{1/n}(a)$ be the open ball centered at $a$ of radius $1/n$. Define $O_n = \bigcup_{a\in C}B_{1/n}(a)$. Since this is a union of open sets it is open (regardless of countability of the union). Furthermore, since it is open it is measurable. Then $C=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty O_n$, and this is a $G_\delta$ set (countable intersection of open/measurable sets and hence measurable).

So then $C$ is measurable. But it was pointed out to me that based on what I have here, $C$ could be replaced with any set, including a non-measurable set. So I'm curious as to what goes wrong here.

Comment: The set $\bigcap_nO_n=\overline{C}$, not $C$,

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544162/discontinuity-set-of-function-closed-and-f-sigma) is a posting that may be relevant to what you want to show.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I see that now, thank you for the answers. Would setting $O_n = \cup_{a\in C} f^{-1}(B_{1/n}(f(a)))$ then be a correct solution? Wouldn't that avoid points of discontinuity?

Comment: You have two answers. If you do not need anything else, accept one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the last equality
$$C \overset{\Huge?}= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty O_n$$
For instance, if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is defined by $f=1$ when $x>0$ and $0$ when $x\le 0$, then $C=\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$, but the intersection over all $O_n$ gives $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $C$ to be the set of all irrational numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ and do what you propose. Then $O_n=\Bbb{R}$ for every $n$ so the intersection of all $O_n$ is not $C$. The same objection applies to your proof.

A correct proof can be found in an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518632/set-of-discontinuous-points). It is actually somewhat similar to what you are trying to do.